# Reading %date% output in a text file using Dos Commands

Tags: batch-file

My requirement is I am Creating a text using dos command to store date using

```
Echo %date% > Sample.txt
```

Now I should read the `Sample.txt` to check for the date value and based on the current date I should call another batch file

Answer (score 0):

This thread ponders your question and has at least one solution: 
 http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=112106.0

1. create another file with today's date
2. compare the files with FC
3. use FIND to check if FC's output says no differences
4. Use FIND's returned error level to branch your batch file

   FC c:\Download\TodayFile.txt c:\Yesterday\File.txt /L | FIND "FC: no dif" > nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto different
    echo Files are the same.
    goto end
    :different echo Files are different.
    :end

Answer (score 0):

WRITE

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
echo %ldt% > test.txt
```

READ

```
   @echo off
    for /f %%a in (test.txt) do (
    echo %%a
    pause
    )
```